# How does one pass semaphore locks and shared objects into threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, locking, parameter-passing

How does one pass semaphore locks into *threading.Thread* objects in Python?

I am using locks to allow different *threading.Thread* classes to modify shared resources in their run functions. However, I'm unsure how to pass in the lock which is declared in a "main" file while the two threading objects are defined in separate files. For example:

Let's say I have one class producing data in *producer.py*:

```
import threading

class producer(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, lock, shared):
    self.lock = lock # Must be linked with global_lock
    self.shared = shared # Must also be linked with global_shared
    self.sock = # Declare listening socket

  def run(self):
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.shared = sock.recv_msg() # Get data from socket
    self.lock.release()
```

And another class consuming data in *consumer.py*:

```
import threading

class consumer(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, lock, shared):
    self.lock = lock # Must be linked with global_lock
    self.shared = shared # Must also be linked with global_shared

  def run(self):
    self.lock.acquire()
    print self.shared
    self.shared = None
    self.lock.release()
```

Then, in *main.py*:

```
import threading

global_lock = threading.Lock()
shared_dictionary = {}

producer_thread = producer(global_lock, global_shared)
consumer_thread = consumer(global_lock, global_shared)
producer.start()
consumer.start()
```

I understand that I could use global variables and declare them at the beginning of the run functions in each class but this is undesired since the purpose of these classes are to be reusable.

How can I pass a shared lock between two threading.Thread objects such that their *.run()* functions use the shared lock and shared object. Please help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not related, but you should use new-style classes (which means your classes should inherit from `object`). I recommend you read a little about new-style classes vs old-style classes :)
Edit: Actually if I understand what you're doing, your should inherit from `Thread`

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The semaphore should be used as an instance variable in both the producer and the consumer. This way, it is shared between each producer-consumer couple and there can be multiple unrelated couples. This is exactly what you did in this code sample. And you don't need do declare anything in the beginning of the `run` function.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I edited the code snippet to reflect that producer and consumer inherit from threading.Thread().

The C/C++ analog of this question would be how do I pass in a pointer to the semaphore lock to the producer and consumer to ensure they are using the same lock? The lock will be declared in a separate main file.

Comment: Hasn't my second comment answered your question?

Comment: Hi Ella, yes it does actually. I didn't think it would be that simple but it turns out passing the lock into the initialization function and declaring an instance variable of a lock within the class was sufficient. Thank you.